# Issue getting code assist for *.cgi files have PHP code

Tags: php, cgi, eclipse-pdt

I am currently working on a project which has files with `.cgi` extensions, but inside they have PHP code. I am not able to get code assist. I am using eclipse PDT as IDE.

I renamed one of the `.cgi` file to `.php` at which point I am able to get code assist.

How can I get code assist for PHP inside of a `.cgi` file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe php is not associated to .cgi? check `General > Editors > File Associations` in settings look for PHP and add new extension there.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml

Comment: thank you for your reply. i already added *.cgi file with PHP editor